# Dropping a block on a vertical spring - derivation with pure kinematics/dynamics (no work-energy)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, calculus

Consider a block of mass $m$ falling on a vertical spring initially contacting the spring at equilibrium point with velocity $v_0$. The spring has constant $k$. I was trying to see if there was a way to derive how far the block falls on the spring / the displacement from equilibrium without using energy or work.

So I set up the position function as:

$$x’’(t)=m(g - kx(t))$$
With initial conditions:
$$x(0)=0$$
$$x’(0)=v_0$$
But I’m not really sure how I would proceed as I haven’t yet taken a diff-eq course, but I have taken calc and know separation of variables and small angle approximations. Is this possible and simple, and I’m just missing something obvious? I’ve been staring at it with no progress. I do know it looks similar to the simple harmonic motion but I’m just looking at the position function until the velocity reaches zero, but I’m now realizing that it may be sinusoidal in nature due to its similarity with SHM.

**Edit:** Mathematica gives me: 
$$x(t)=\frac{gm-gm\cos(\sqrt{k}t)+v_0*\sqrt{k}\sin(\sqrt{k}t)}{k}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your equation should be $$x''(t)=g-\frac {k}{m}x (t) $$ Always check your units! Define $u(t)=x(t)-\frac{mg}{k}$. Notice that $u''(t)=x''(t)$ and $-\frac {k}{m}u(t)=-\frac {k}{m}x(t)+g$, so your differential equation is
$$u''(t)=-\frac {k}{m}u(t)$$

Which I'm sure you recognise as the simple harmonic oscillator. Solve this equation, find $u(t)$ and then resubstitute to find $x(t)$.